# Regex replaces all spaces after group on line

Tags: php, regex, replace, space

Okay... that question sounds strange, but what I mean is this:

I have a specific group to search for, and I want every space AFTER that group, but only on the current line, to be stripped out. My specific example is this:

```
@subpackage Some Word Stuff
```

`@subpackage` does not accept whitespace, but I didn't know that at the time, and I have many many of these lines to fix. I'd like to do a find and replace with regex (my IDE supports this) to strip out the white spaces between the words after EVERY instance of `@subpackage`.

EDIT: Clarity by example perhaps

```
"@subpackage Some Word Stuff" -> "@subpackage SomeWordStuff"
```

Comment: difficult to understand :(

Comment: So you want `Some Word Stuff` to become `SomeWordStuff`?

Comment: is `@subpackage` always at the start of the line?

Comment: Yes, and yes. I want any line BEGINNING with "@subpackage" to have everything after "@subpackace " stripped of whitespace.

So that line would become "@subpackage SomeWordStuff"

Answer (score 1):

Find using below regex, replace with empty string `''` .
(Just use replace_all)

```
 # '~(?mi-)(?:(?!\A)\G|^@subpackage)[^ \r\n]*\K[ ]+~'

 (?xmi-)                     # Inline 'Expanded, multiline, case insensitive' modifiers
 (?:
      (?! \A )                    # Matched before, start from here
      \G                          
   |                            # or,
      ^ @subpackage               # '@Subpackage' at bol (remove '^' if not at bol)
 )
 [^ \r\n]*                   # Not space or line breaks
 \K                          # Don't include anything from here back in match
 [ ]+                        # 1 or more spaces
```

Here is one for all non-linebreak whitespace.

```
 # '~(?mi-)(?:(?!\A)\G|^@subpackage)\S*\K[^\S\r\n]+~'

 (?xmi-)                     # Inline 'Expanded, multiline, case insensitive' modifiers
 (?:
      (?! \A )                    # Matched before, start from here
      \G                          
   |                            # or,
      ^ @subpackage               # '@Subpackage' at bol (remove '^' if not at bol)
 )
 \S*                         # 0 or more, Not whitespace
 \K                          # Don't include anything from here back in match
 [^\S\r\n]+                  # 1 or more non-linebreak whitespaces
```

Comment: I'm not sure that works. I tested it here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/. I believe the IDE I use (PHP storm) follows the method of preg_replace